# I'm getting an error: Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. I'm having trouble formatting it in the way it wants

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this error back though this same format seems to work in examples.

````
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-tasks')

    const dataObject = response.data
    

    const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(dataObject)
    const arrayOfData = Object.keys(dataObject).map((key) => dataObject[key])

    console.log(arrayOfKeys)
    console.log(arrayOfData)
  }, [])```
````

Comment: Use `then` instead of `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The useEffect function arg can't be asynchronous, but you can call an async function inside it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getTasks() {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-tasks')

    const dataObject = response.data

    const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(dataObject)
    const arrayOfData = Object.keys(dataObject).map((key) => dataObject[key])

    console.log(arrayOfKeys)
    console.log(arrayOfData)
  };

  getTasks();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions return a `Promise`, and `useEffect` does not expect a `Promise` returned.  (If anything is returned at all, it should be a function for cleanup of any effects when a component is unmounted.)

If you want to use async/await in `useEffect` then you can wrap the whole thing in an `async` IIFE.  For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-tasks');
    const dataObject = response.data;

    const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(dataObject);
    const arrayOfData = Object.keys(dataObject).map((key) => dataObject[key]);

    console.log(arrayOfKeys);
    console.log(arrayOfData);
  })();
}, []);
```

Alternatively, you can use `.then()` on the inner `async` operation instead of `await`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-tasks').then(response => {
    const dataObject = response.data;

    const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(dataObject);
    const arrayOfData = Object.keys(dataObject).map((key) => dataObject[key]);

    console.log(arrayOfKeys);
    console.log(arrayOfData);
  });
}, []);
```